# Cannot use Voice Isolation with AVAudioRecorder or AudioUnit

Tags: swift, audiounit, avaudiorecorder, ios15

I'm trying to record voice audio with either `AVAudioRecorder` or `AUAudioUnit`.

In both, after a recording has started, whenever calling `AVCaptureDevice.showSystemUserInterface(.microphoneModes)` and selecting voice isolation, I get the following error:

"Voice Isolation and Wide Spectrum are currently unavailable"

TLDR: What do I need to allow the user to change to voice isolation mode?

Comment: Per this video, Mic Modes are only available through AVCaptureDevice: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10047/?time=1384

Answer (score 1):

I have an application that plays audio in real time and the audio separation mode is available by writing the following.

```
private let audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()

//　omission (of middle part of a text)

let audioInput = audioEngine.inputNode
audioInput.isVoiceProcessingBypassed = true
do {
    try audioInput.setVoiceProcessingEnabled(true)
} catch {
    print("Could not enable voice processing \(error)")
    return
}
let audioFormat = audioEngine.inputNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
audioEngine.connect(audioInput, to: audioEngine.mainMixerNode, format:audioFormat)
```

Since I am using AVAudioEngine, I believe your objective can be achieved by simply changing the AVAudioEngine output destination.